# F95 Send/Receive Memory Errors for Array Sending

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I'm new to parallel programming and attempting to produce a sparse matrix-vector calculation in Fortran 95. I'm working on a subprogram that only gathers the components of the vector that the sparse matrix will touch (instead of `MPI_AllGather`), but I keep getting SIGSESV errors. I know this means I've asked the process to touch something it can't/doesn't exist, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it could be.

```
!Gather the vector matrix in matrix vector multiplication for sparse matrices

subroutine sparsegather(u,BW,myid,nprocs)

  use header
  include "mpif.h"

  type(Vector), intent(inout) :: u
  integer,intent(in) :: BW !Bandwidth
  integer,intent(in) :: myid !process id
  integer,intent(in) :: nprocs !number of processes

  integer :: n, i
  integer,dimension(BW) :: rlr, rrr, slr, srr !Range of receive left/right, send left/right
  real(kind=rk),dimension(BW) :: rl, rr, sl, sr !Arrays of actual values

  integer :: ierr

  n = u%n  !Length of whole vector - used in periodic condition

  !Define ranges
  do i = 1,BW
     rlr(i) = u%ibeg - BW - 1 + i
     rrr(i) = u%iend + i

     srr(i) = u%iend - i + 1
     slr(i) = u%ibeg + i - 1
  end do

  !Periodic conditions
  do i = 1,BW
     if (rlr(i) < 1) then
        rlr(i) = rlr(i) + n
     end if
     if ((srr(i) < 1) then
        srr(i) = srr(i) + n
     end if
     if (rrr(i) > n ) then
        rrr(i) = rrr(i) - n
     end if
     if (slr(i) > n ) then
        slr(i) = slr(i) - n
     end if
  end do

  !Store the matrix values being sent over
  sl = u%xx(slr)
  sr = u%xx(srr)

  !Pass the value parcels around
  if (myid == 0) then 
     call MPI_Recv(rl,BW,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,nprocs-1,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
     call MPI_Send(sr,BW,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,myid+1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
     call MPI_Recv(rr,BW,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,myid+1,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
     call MPI_Send(sl,BW,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,nprocs-1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
  elseif (myid == nprocs-1) then
     call MPI_Send(sr,BW,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
     call MPI_Recv(rl,BW,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,myid-1,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
     call MPI_Send(sl,BW,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,myid-1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
     call MPI_Recv(rr,BW,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
  elseif (mod(myid,2) == 0) then 
     call MPI_Recv(rl,BW,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,myid-1,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
     call MPI_Send(sr,BW,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,myid+1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
     call MPI_Recv(rr,BW,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,myid+1,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
     call MPI_Send(sl,BW,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,myid-1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
  else
     call MPI_Send(sr,BW,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,myid+1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
     call MPI_Recv(rl,BW,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,myid-1,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
     call MPI_Send(sl,BW,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,myid-1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
     call MPI_Recv(rr,BW,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,myid+1,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
  end if

  u%xx(rrr) = rr
  u%xx(rlr) = rl

end subroutine sparsegather
```

`u` is an object with the vector values stored in `%xx` and its size in `%n`. The relevant starting point and end points for each processor are in `%ibeg` and `%iend`.

`BW` is bandwith of the sparse banded matrix. This equation has periodic conditions, so values to the left of the start of the vector wrap around to the right side (and vice versa), which is done in the periodic conditions section.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Very few people follow the [tag:fortran95] tag. You did not break any etiquette, I just removed the thank you lines as we usually remove these as a distraction.

Comment: It is recommended to use the MPI module using `use mpi` instead of including the `mpif.h` file. That way the compiler is able to do more checks for you and find certain kinds of errors. Olso, it is good to tell us which MPI library you use and which compiler you use. And finally, the subroutine will not be enough code, because we cannot test it on its won, we need a full code we can try to run, although as short as possible [mcve] and also the complete output. Do not forget to use the deubging flags like `gfortran -g -fbacktrace --Wall -fcheck=all`.

Comment: [Edit] As a matter of style (and to keep your code concise and correct with an odd number of tasks) you might want to consider using `MPI_Sendrecv()`.

Comment: ...and do arithmetic on ranks rather than duplicate call pairs 4 times.